# Change django bound data in UpdateView

Tags: django

I'd like to prefill a field, regardless what's in there already, on an update view so a user can just hit save and save the new value. If there is already data in there, I can't use `initial`.

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Artwork
    fields = ['template',]
    template_name = 'page.html'

    def get_form(self):
        form = super(MyView, self).get_form()
        form.fields['template'].initial = 'hello'
        return form
```

This doesn't work because there is data in `template`. So I tried

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Artwork
    fields = ['template',]
    template_name = 'page.html'

    def get_form(self):
        form = super(MyView, self).get_form()
        form.data['template']= 'hello'
        return form
```

But the value in the form is the saved value. I'd read form.data would do this, but it was an 8 year old answer. So not sure how to do this in Django 3.0.6

in case helpful:

print(form.data): `<MultiValueDict: {}>`

print(form): `<tr><th><label for="id_template">Template:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="template" maxlength="100" id="id_template"></td></tr>`

print(form.fields): `{'template': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f937ae20bd0>}`

print(self.get_form_kwargs()): `{'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'instance': <Artwork: Tim>}`

Comment: You can. add a method `def get_initial(self): return {'template':'hello'} ` to solve this issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a few ways to work around this

- Override get_initial method
- Update request.POST dictionary
- Ovrride `get_form_kwargs` method

**get_initial**

Get initial returns a dictionary of the field name to value 
so simply adding following code should work

```
def get_initial():
    return {'template' : 'foo' }
```

**get_form**

In `get_form` method update request.POST as

```
def get_form(self):
  # note this may raise immutability error then completely change 
  # `request.POST` to cloned with the new key,values.
  self.request.POST['template'] =  'foo'
  form = super(MyView, self).get_form()
  return form
```

**get_form_kwargs**

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """Return the keyword arguments for instantiating the form."""
    kwargs = {
        'initial': self.get_initial(),
        'prefix': self.get_prefix(),
    }

    if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
        kwargs.update({
            'data': self.request.POST,
            'files': self.request.FILES,
        })
        # here update data with new key/val pairs
     return kwargs
```